# Mycelium Gear testnet confirmation

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, testnet

When I send payment to a testnet address generated by Mycelium Gear, it doesn't see the transaction even when it's included in a block.
`Blockcypher.com, blockexplorer.com, blockchain.info and blocktrail.com` see the transaction, though `blocktrail` seems to have indexing lag: it can't find the transaction by payment address, only by transaction id.

If Gear uses blocktrail API, this could be the reason.

Does anyone know a workaround, without using block chain exploration apis by myself?